# Django - multiple joins on same table - incorrect result?

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I have the following model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    ...

class DocumentAttributes(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document)
    key = models.TextField()
    value = models.TextField()
```

I want to query documents based on attributes. The specified keys must match one of the values.

Probably best with an example:

```
    self.d1 = document_factory(attributes={'a': '1', 'b': '1'})
    self.d2 = document_factory(attributes={'a': '2', 'b': '2'})
    self.d3 = document_factory(attributes={'a': '2', 'b': '1'})
    self.d4 = document_factory(attributes={'a': '3', 'b': '4'})
    self.d5 = document_factory(attributes={'a': '3', 'b': '2'})
    self.d6 = document_factory(attributes={'a': '1', 'b': '4'})
    self.d7 = document_factory(attributes={'a': '2', 'b': '4'})

 docs = whitelist_keyvalue_in({'a': ['1', '3'], 'b': ['1', '4']}, doc_qs).all()
```

Docs should now contain d1, d4, d6.

Here is my implementation:

```
def whitelist_keyvalue_in(json_obj, doc_qs):
    qs = doc_qs
    for key in json_obj:
        values = [json_obj[key]] if isinstance(json_obj[key], basestring) else json_obj[key]
        q_values = Q()
        for v in values:
            q_values |= Q(value=v)
        qs = qs.filter(attributes=DocumentAttributes.objects.filter(key=key).filter(q_values))
    print(qs.query)
    return qs
```

For some reason, this only returns d1? and the generated query is not exactly beautiful.

Can you spot any mistake? Is there a better way to write this?

```
SELECT ... FROM "document_document"
INNER JOIN "document_documentattributes" ON ("document_document"."id" = "document_documentattributes"."document_id")
INNER JOIN "document_documentattributes" T3 ON ("document_document"."id" = T3."document_id")
WHERE
("document_documentattributes"."id" = ( SELECT U0."id"
                       FROM "document_documentattributes" U0
                       WHERE (U0."key" = 'a' AND (U0."value" = '1' OR U0."value" = '3')))
                       AND T3."id" = ( SELECT U0."id"
                                FROM "document_documentattributes" U0
                                WHERE (U0."key" = 'b' AND (U0."value" = '1' OR U0."value" = '4'))))
```

If I do it myself with a raw query things work fine:

```
def whitelist_keyvalue_in(json_obj, doc_qs):
    names = {key: 'da{}'.format(k_index) for k_index, key in enumerate(json_obj)}
    raw_sql = "SELECT da0.document_id as id FROM document_documentattributes as da0 "
    for key in json_obj:
        if names[key] == 'da0':
            continue
        raw_sql += ("JOIN document_documentattributes as {0} ON {0}.document_id = da0.document_id "
                    "".format(names[key]))
    for key in json_obj:
        where_and = 'WHERE' if names[key] == 'da0' else ' AND'
        values = [json_obj[key]] if isinstance(json_obj[key], basestring) else json_obj[key]
        values_opts = ' OR '.join("{}.value = '{}'".format(names[key], value) for value in values)
        raw_sql += "{} {}.key = '{}' AND ({})".format(where_and, names[key], key, values_opts)
    return doc_qs.filter(id__in=(d.id for d in doc_qs.raw(raw_sql)))
```

which gives:

```
SELECT da0.document_id as id 
FROM document_documentattributes as da0 
JOIN document_documentattributes as da1 ON da1.document_id = da0.document_id 
WHERE da0.key = 'a' AND (da0.value = '1' OR da0.value = '3') 
  AND da1.key = 'b' AND (da1.value = '1' OR da1.value = '4')

SELECT ... FROM "document_document" WHERE "document_document"."id" IN (1, 4, 6)
```

I would prefer to avoid the id__in but could not figure out how to get from a raw query set to a regular query set.

If I have to use raw sql for this, is there a way I can avoid the two selects to return a normal query set?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the ` id__in` filter ?

Comment: @MevinBabu - I already have the list of documents that I care about. The id__in performs a second unnecessary query which can also be a slow query depending on how many documents there are.

Comment: you mean to say that you already have a query which returns you a list of documents and then you want to filter this list again to return documents that match the attributes ? and hence you don't want to do two different queries ? right?

Comment: But your `whitelist_keyvalue_in` function is anyway firing a new query to the db ?

Comment: @MevinBabu - not quite. QuerySets stores the info it needs to perform SQL queries - it won't hit the DB until it has to. When I use a raw sql query it will hit the DB immediately, giving a list of PK:s. However, I want to return a QuerySet (handy for subsequent operations). The only way I can return a QuerySet given a list of PKs is to do a id__in. Now I will always hit the db twice. I wish there was some way to take a raw sql giving PKs and turn that into a QuerySet without hitting the db to fetch PKs (i.e. Django would use it as a sql subquery). Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally figured out how to get it right. The generated raw query is even nice to look at.

```
def whitelist_keyvalue_in(attributes, doc_qs):
    qs = doc_qs
    for key, values in attributes.iteritems():
        values = [values] if isinstance(values, basestring) else values
        qs = qs.filter(attributes__key=key, attributes__value__in=values)
    return qs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

`qs = qs.filter(attributes=DocumentAttributes.objects.filter(key=key).filter(q_values))` is inside the for loop and every time a filter is applied, it behaves like an `and` condition. Hence the final query will be to fetch documents with where `a is 1 or 3 and b is 1 or 4`. Here d1 matches the criteria and return because it has `a = 1` and `b = 1`.

Using the `Q()` with `|` around each key should solve this problem.

This line `qs = qs.filter(attributes=DocumentAttributes.objects.filter(key=key).filter(q_values))` will fire two queries because `DocumentAttributes.objects.filter(key=key).filter(q_values)` will get evaluated to be used in the `qs` query

Comment: Your analysis is not correct. Note that: qs.filter returns a new filter, it is iteratively building up a query set. Your suggestion is also not correct - it will return the empty set whenever querying for more than one attribute. (And note that the "if key in filter_dic:" that will never be the case.)

Comment: This part `DocumentAttributes.objects.filter(key=key).filter(q_values)` will get evaluated to be used in the `qs.filter` query

Comment: yeah your right. I got things mixed up. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Still not correct. " it behaves like an and condition" that is exactly what I want. "a is 1 or 3 and b is 1 or 4" also exactly what I want, but note that d1 is not the only one that matches this criteria. It really should return: d1, d4, d6.

Comment: "will fire two queries because " no it won't. The benefit with the query set (as I stated previously), is that you can work on an abstract query *without* firing sql statements to the db until you need them. For example: qs = Documents.objects.all(). Will not execute any query. If I then do qs2 = qs.filter(something=something) - it still won't exeecute any query. Only when I actually am fetching data will a query be sent. For example doc = qs2.all()[0].

Comment: you got me wrong. `DocumentAttributes.objects.filter(key=key).filter(q_values)` will be executed and its value is passed to `qs.filter`. Yes the `qs` query wont be fired.